# Enumerating functions modulo action on both the domain and codomain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory

Let $Hom(A,B)$ be the set of functions from a finite set $A$ to a finite set $B$ and let $G_A \leq S_A$, $G_B \leq S_B$ be a subgroups of the permutation groups of $A$ and $B$.  For $f,g \in Hom(A,B)$ define $f \sim g$ iff there exists $r \in {G_A}$, $s \in {G_B}$ such that $f(x) = s \cdot g(r \cdot x)$ for all $x \in A$.

The enumeration of $Hom(A,B) / \sim$ is called Polya's Theory of Enumeration, I believe.  However, my present references do not cover the case where both $G_A$ and $G_B$ may be intermediate (non-trivial and non-full) permutation subgroups.

What is the best reference for this general case?  There is a book called "Applied Finite Group Actions" by Kerber, but I don't have a copy.  Is there an online reference for this topic?

Comment: If I understand this correctly what you are talking about here is Power Group Enumeration, which may be learned from Harary & Palmer's text *Graphical Enumeration.* This is an older text which is not perfect but I recommend it for the simplicity of the writing and the proofs.